# How to count the number of records in a table with the same value

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I paste the table's records, so that you can help me to make a query.

```
........................................
car_id  | mark    | model   | prize
........................................
    1   | fiat    | 500     | 15000
    2   | fiat    | panda   | 8000
    3   | opel    | astra   | 20000
    4   | renault | clio    | 14000
    5   | opel    | corsa   | 12000
    6   | fiat    | panda   | 8000
    7   | fiat    | 500     | 15000
    8   | renault | capture | 16000
    9   | renault | clio    | 14000
    10  | fiat    | 500     | 15000
```

I would like, with a query, to know the amount of models in the dealership for each type of car (mark & model). In simple words, I would get a result like this:

```
........................................
  mark    | model   | Quantity
........................................
  fiat    | 500     | 3
  fiat    | panda   | 2
  opel    | astra   | 1 
  opel    | corsa   | 1
  renault | clio    | 2
  renault | capture | 1
```

Which query could create a table like that?

Comment: As simple as: `SELECT mark, model, COUNT(*) AS quantity FROM tab GROUP BY mark, model`. I can bet you didn't even try.

Comment: I'm learning the rules of mysql and tried in various ways, but never succeed. Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a group by statement for doing it.

```
select mark, model,count(*) as Quantity 
from <tableName>
group by mark,model;
```